# Return Moment array in JS

Tags: reactjs, typescript, momentjs

After parsing my dates into an array, I would like to store it in a moment UseState Array.

```
  const [yearperiod, setYearPeriod ] = React.useState([moment("2021-09-09")])


  const startdate : any = (document.getElementById('startdate') as HTMLInputElement);
  const enddate : any = (document.getElementById('enddate') as HTMLInputElement);
  
  const dateStart = moment(startdate.value, "DD-MM-YYYY")
  const dateEnd = moment(enddate.value, "DD-MM-YYYY")
  const interim = dateStart.clone();
  const timeValues = [];

  while (dateEnd > interim || interim.format('MM') === dateEnd.format('MM')) {
    timeValues.push(interim.format('MM-YYYY'));
    interim.add(1,'month');
 }

  // ERROR
  setYearPeriod(timeValues)
```

but I have the following error:

```
Argument of type 'string[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<Moment[]>'.
```

Comment: before pushing dates to the `timeValues` try create moment objects with them

Answer (score 0):

```
  const [yearperiod, setYearPeriod ] = React.useState([moment("2021-09-09")])
```

So because you set your initial state to be an array containing a moment object it will expect the same structure whenever you want to update your state, that's how typescript works if you dont specify a type.

What you're passing down is an array of strings, but this should be an array of moment objects, because of that initial state update.

```
const momentItems = timeValues.map(item => moment(item)); 


setYearPeriod(momentItems)
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, I am aware of this situation. My question was more about how to return a Moment Array

Comment: I'm not sure if this will work, but i have updated my code @LikiTiki